# Is it possible to set FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath with "..//..//FolderName" in C#?

Tags: c#, folderbrowserdialog

```
FolderBrowserDialog openfolderdialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
openfolderdialog1.SelectedPath = "..\\..\\Gambar Train\\";
if (openfolderdialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    textBox1.Text = openfolderdialog1.SelectedPath;
}
```

It is not working. Do you have solution for this ?
i want to use "..\.." cause the folder location is not fixed.

Comment: Does that folder exist?

Comment: "not working", what **exactly** do you mean by that?

Comment: Its working fine. Only the issue is either assign openfolderdialog1.SelectedPath property directly with relative path or instantiate new DirectoryInfo and assign openfolderdialog1.SelectedPath = TrainFolderLocation.FullName.

Comment: yup, it's working, but the selected path is still root folder (Desktop) not my relative folder which is "..\\..\\Gambar Train".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ..\ is a 'relative' path, you need to define what its relative to.

So "..\..\folder\" will work (your example isn't because `SelectedPath` is a string), but you can't say 100% where that location will be.

I would look at things like the `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` or `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` and base your location on that.

Comment: do you know how to give focus at selected path ? cause the dialog show up but the focus still in root folder

Comment: If your setting the `SelectedPath` but the dialog isn't at that path, my first thought would be it doesn't exist, or you don't have access.

Comment: it's already there but my view is still at the top or the rootfolder.

Answer (score 1):

Set the SelectedPath property before you call ShowDialog ...

```
folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = @"c:\temp\";
folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

Will start them at C:\Temp

## [SelectedPath Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.selectedpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectedPath` property is a `string`, not a `DirectoryInfo`.

Try

```
openfolderdialog1.SelectedPath = "..\\..\\Gambar Train\\";
```

Comment: i forgot to edit the question. I already changed it to string, the problem is my folder is relative (..\\..\\) not (C:\\test\\)